# XCode 3.2.6 stack damage after function call

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode

I have a very strange issue with a very simple "demo" application. 
Basically the issue is that if I make a class method call with a single argument and this method returns immediately but has variables defined after the return (see below) then the call stack gets damaged and some other variables are changed... I know that this sounds crazy but here is the code...

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {    
    // Override point for customization after application launch.

    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];

    NSError *er=[MLRESTRequest test:nil];  //<- this line modifies the "application" variable passed as first argument!

    return YES;
}


@implementation MLRESTRequest
+ (NSError*) test:(id)task
{
    return nil;

    NSURLResponse *responseHeaders=nil;
    NSDictionary *responseHeadersDict=nil;
    NSError *error=nil;
    NSData *result=nil;
    NSURL *urlToCall = nil;
    NSMutableURLRequest *urlRequest=nil;    
    NSString *serverRequest=nil;
    NSString *cookie=nil;

    NSString *server=nil;
    NSString *port=nil;
    NSString *call=nil;
    //return nil;
}
@end
```

If I move the return at the end of the "test" method then all is OK...

Edit: I post images of the issue in comments

Edit2: I re-imaged the mac and installed a fresh copy of xCode 3.2.6 - the problem vanished. Sadly after few days I started to have similar issues...(a stack variable gets changed without any reason after returning from function call)... I recompiled exactly the same code on 3.2.5 and 4.0 and the issue vanished again... I don't know what to do but for now will stay away from 3.2.6

Edit3: If some one is still interested about this case - I have proves that the GCC 4.2 used in 3.2.6 is buggy - if the LLVM + GCC 4.2 is used then there is no crash

Comment: What's the purpose of the code after the `return` statement? Is it ever reached?

Comment: no purpose - this code is only for "demo" - I have issues with much complex project and narrow the issue to this problem...i.e. having a variable defined after the return...if I remove the vars or move the return after them - its OK...

Comment: What version of XCode and what compiler are you using? Lately, I've seen a few problems that could be tracked down to the compiler producing invalid code - though it has only affected release mode so far.

Comment: Some images to show more info about the issue (i cant upload here because of my low rating)
 
http://img194.imageshack.us/img194/469/beforecall.png

http://img685.imageshack.us/img685/9119/incall1.png

http://img692.imageshack.us/img692/7287/aftercall.png

http://img560.imageshack.us/img560/6076/crashh.png

http://img231.imageshack.us/img231/3295/projsettings.png

http://img717.imageshack.us/img717/5849/targetsettings.png

http://img840.imageshack.us/img840/972/xcode.png


Please help - tell me what I am doing wrong or is there a possible issue with the xCode?

Answer (score 2):

Are you debugging this in release mode? Or Debug mode? If you're in release mode, you can't really trust anything the debugger tells you about this kind of thing.

Comment: In debug mode - if I try to access the "damaged" application variable - a "normal" EXC_BAD_ACCESS is generated...

Comment: There is something you're not telling us then, or you're misreading what is happening.

Answer (score 1):

The only way `application` is going to be modified in that code, as posted, is if you are compiling with optimization enabled.  End of story.

The implementation of `test:`, regardless of where the return statement is, does pretty much absolutely nothing and it certainly won't affect the parent stack frame.

As Joshua said, you haven't given enough information to tell you what is going on.  Post the crash's backtrace, for starters.

Answer (score 0):

Based on your comment to Joshua Weinberg, it sounds like you are trying to access variables that have been optimized away, i.e. the variables that are declared *below* the return.  Don't do that!